Consecutive "<,>" characters in bicep string parameters causing "> was unexpected at this time"
Similar to previously a answered question: Bicep/ARM XML parameter as string not parsed correctly. Which indicated you needed to escape the ">" or "<" with quotes.  This is one hit a bit different.  In this bicep deployment example, if the value passed in contains consecutive '>', '<' in either order, you'll receive an error similar to: "< was unexpected at this time."
the simple example bicep file is:
targetScope = 'subscription'

output esc_str string = escape_str

then deployed such as:
az deployment sub create --name test --location eastus --template-file .\BicepTest.bicep --parameters escape_str='abc<>'
my scenario is a little more complex than that. but the general idea is there.
I can get this to work if i put both the <> in quotes as such:
az deployment sub create --name test --location eastus --template-file .\BicepTest.bicep --parameters escape_str='abc"<>"'
however, that value is a variable that is passed in so it is more in the form of escape_str=$variable format (Powershell), and we don't necessarily know the combinations that will cause this to error.
I'm wondering if there is a safe way to "escape" a set of characters, or if there are other limitations.  The Bicep reference doesn't indicate these characters required to be escaped.
At the moment, I have a few lines such as (also with the different combinations we have found):
$x.replace('<>','"<>"')
This works, but only for those combinations of characters, and something like ">>", ">>>" would also error as well, although the first would just give "The syntax of the command is incorrect".  I'm looking for potentially a better solution for this.  Any Ideas?

Added the azure-cli tag as it probably linked tot he way the cli escape special characters

Also do you have a sample string: like a real case scenario ? Are you trying to pass xml string or something ?

have you check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-azure-cli-successfully-quoting?tabs=powershell1%2Cbash2%2Cpowershell3

in powershell, I have defined a variable like that: $variable="abc<>" then use it like that  --parameters escape_str=`""$variable"`". That worked for me.

That seems to work perfectly!  Thank you.
And to answer previous question, there was some xml/html, mostly where tags were consecutive and also some random password being passed into a deployment for keyvault or services (SQL) admin passwords, (using @secure decorator), that had consecutive values.

Glad it solve your issue


Consecutive "<,>" characters in bicep string parameters causing "> was unexpected at this time

I agree with Thomas on the point mentioned a variable like that: $variable="abc<>" then use it like that --parameters escape_str=`""$variable"`".
Specially when the special characters being passed to your Bicep template through PowerShell. Special characters such as <, >, or & are treated specially by PowerShell and the command shell.
When youre using powershell it provides the special character (`)
  $variable = "abc<>"

This is the case with powershell.
and while using bicep deployement command you can use that
az deployment sub create --name test --location eastus --template-file .\BicepTest.bicep --parameters escape_str="`"$variable"`"

This should work fine as expected without any blocker.
Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-azure-cli-successfully-quoting?tabs=powershell1%2Cbash2%2Cpowershell3
For the info related to special characters.
